# Multiple Natural Attacks

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, natural-weapon

Let's say I have a summoned eagle (or anything else with multiple NAs). Eagles have 3 primary attacks (2x Talons, 1x Bite). I want to understand the consequences of the various actions I can take, this is my current understanding:

- Full Attack Action: With a full attack action I can take all 3 primary attacks at their regular bonus with their regular damage. All the attacks remain primary attacks and are not considered secondary attacks. Similarly any secondary attacks would still be considered secondary.
- Standard Action: With a standard action I can make one attack. If the attack is a primary attack it remains so. If the attack is a secondary attack it also remains so.
- Full Attack Action (with a sword): Let's assume I got my eagle a tiny sword that it can somehow wield (using one of its talons I guess). Now with a full attack action I can stab with the sword at full BAB (+0) and take each natural attack (presumably not including the one in the talon wielding the sword) as secondary attacks (-5 to hit, -1/2 str bonus).

Is this correct?